# Java - Integer.parseInt() not returning a negative number when radix=2

Tags: java, binary, parseint

As far as I know, when using 2's complement, and the first number is a 1, then you flip the numbers and find the value of the new byte and make it a negative.The javadoc says that Integer.parseInt(String s, radix) and Integer.valueOf(String s, radix) both should return a signed integer object, but when I test it out with this:

```
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt("10000001", 2));

System.out.println(Integer.valueOf("10000001", 2));
```

I get:

```
129

129
```

even though my calculations get me -127. Whats interesting is that

```
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt("-10000001", 2));
```

prints out:

```
-129
```

Anyone know of a different java method that if you input a byte (and radix = 2), then the method will return a correctly signed value?

Comment: Maybe because it's returning an `int` instead of a `byte`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it's always going to be a byte, then this should do the trick:

```
int i = Integer.parseInt("10000001", 2);
byte b = (byte) i;
```

The integer value will be 129, but when you cast it to a byte it will change to -127.

Comment: NumberFormatException: Value out of range. Value:"10000001" Radix:2

Comment: What is wrong with `byte b = Byte.parseByte("10000001", 2);`?

Comment: As far as I'm aware the parseByte method is only for unsigned bytes, and so reads the number as 129, which is larger than a byte can hold, and so a NumberFormatException will be thrown.

Comment: Your code also reads it as 129 too but it fits in a byte. Looks like parseByte expects a strictly mathematical representation of the number with '-' when negative. The sign bit is a computer thing. Your answer is correct. The JVM represents the bytes as ints internally anyway.

Answer (score 2):

So you want

```
Integer.parseInt("1", 2) == -1?
```

You can always parse the string as a 32 bit integer, then if the value is 128-255, convert it to its negative complement manually.

Comment: no, im loking for something like Integer.parseInt("[8-bit number]",2) = the correctly signed number

Comment: Looks like a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Integer.parseInt(String s,int radix)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

> Parses the string argument as a signed integer in the radix specified
>   by the second argument. The characters in the string must all be
>   digits of the specified radix (as determined by whether
>   Character.digit(char, int) returns a nonnegative value), except that
>   the first character may be an ASCII minus sign '-' ('\u002D') to
>   indicate a negative value. The resulting integer value is returned.

So Integer.parseInt("anyvalue", 2) will never return -some value  unless first character is not '-'.

Comment: Unless they are your own words you should reference where you found them.

Answer (score 0):

This is because for int 10000001 is not -127,  int has 32 bits and to this is 31st which determines whether the number is negative or not. If we think that 10000001 is -127 then it is a byte, not int. But Byte.parseByte("10000001", 2) cannot parse two's complement representation and will throw NumberFormatException. The only way to parse two's complement representation in Java SE is

```
byte b = new BigInteger("10000001", 2).byteValue();
```

this will produce expected -127

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = -4;

    /* returns the string representation of the unsigned integer value 
    represented by the argument in binary (base 2) */

    String convertedString  = Integer.toBinaryString(i);

    System.out.println(convertedString);

    /* Converting the binary format string back to integer value */
    int foo = new BigInteger(convertedString, 2).intValue();

    System.out.println(foo);
}
```